# How to change TinyMCE v.5 cursor type when changing table column width?

Tags: tinymce

In tinyMCE v.5 when changing table column width, as a functionality of table plugin, I have cursor: default, but on their website on example https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/basic-example/# cursor is: col-resize. How can I change it to be col-resize also? :)

Could'n find on their website that that this is some customization option, it looks like default look, but in my project is showing different than on their example.

Here is the Screenshot https://prnt.sc/nlfza0

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some custom CSS in that screenshot - the toolbar should wrap, not scroll.

The cursor is set via a content stylesheet, which uses `cursor: row-resize` (or `cursor: col-resize`) when the cursor is over invisible `div` elements that line up with the table borders.

You can use a DOM inspector to find the elements (they're siblings of the `body` tag) and the element style information should tell you where the cursor is being overridden.

If that doesn't help, please create a replication example on our http://fiddle.tinymce.com website (or other fiddle/codepen type website) and we'll see if we can track it down.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Spyder :)

I found them, you're right they are sibilings of body :)

They have classes:
"ephox-snooker-resizer-rows ephox-snooker-resizer-bar" - resize row 
"ephox-snooker-resizer-cols ephox-snooker-resizer-bar" - resize column

and get additional class "ephox-snooker-resizer-bar-dragging" while in dragging mode.

I just added this properties in a "tinymce/css/mycontent.css" file:

```
/* TABLE RESIZE COLUMN - CURSOR TYPE */

.ephox-snooker-resizer-cols {
cursor: col-resize;
}

.ephox-snooker-resizer-rows {
cursor: ns-resize;
}
```